# Eigenvectors of a Homothety operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that every non-zero vector is an eigenvector of the Linear Operator L

$\iff$

L is the Homothety Operator v $\rightarrow \alpha v\;$ where $\alpha$ is some fixed scalar

One direction is trivial but im having a hard time proving that every non zero vector is an eigenvectors implies that it's a homothety.

Help Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: It's probably easier to approach the "hard" direction as a contrapositive. So, suppose $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $L$ with distinct eigenvalues. What can you say about $v + w$? (Particularly, is it an eigenvector of $L$?)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the matrix of the operator in an arbitrary basis?